# How to change 100 files from .xlsb to .xlsx in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have hundreds of excel files that need to be uploaded, but are currently in file type `.xlsb`

I need them to be file type `.xlsx`

Don't really know much about excel macros so I am looking for help.

Tried using some code I found online that uses VBA through excel's macro dev function (Sorry for poor wording, I'm an excel novice).

```
  Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
  'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
  'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim myPath As String
  Dim myFile As String
  Dim myExtension As String
  Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
  Dim fpath As String
  Dim wname As String


  'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

      With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
          If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
          myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
      End With

  'In Case of Cancel
  NextCode:
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

  'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.xls*"

  'Target Path with Ending Extention
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

  'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    Do While myFile <> ""
      'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
        wname = Left(wb.Name, InStr(wb.Name, ".") - 1)
        fpath = wb.Path & "\" & wname


      'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents

      'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.SaveAs Filename:=fpath & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
          xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

      'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents

      'Get next file name
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

  'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"

  ResetSettings:
    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
      Application.EnableEvents = True
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
```

I get a

> runtime error "1004":
>
> This extension cannot be used with this file type.

Comment: The error message is spot on, `FileFormat:=xlExcel12` refers to binary workbooks only. Try changing that line to `FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

You must open each workbook and save it as XLSX; you can't simple change the extension from XLSB to XLSX.  The code below will do what you want.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xlsb"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Save and Close Workbook
    wb.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```